# Is using a long string in a GET variable a secure way of identifying a user?

Tags: security, language-agnostic, twilio

I am making a Twilio app.  Twilio can send a request to the server after a call is over, but it isn't able to be associated with the logged in user of my website because Twilio is making an independent request.  If I were to tell Twilio to post something at

```
example.com/response.html?token=ba38pgab38g4agdusoehle8qihxs&data=somedata
```

and then use this token as a way of verifying that this Twilio request is associated with a user, is that secure?

I have seen this technique used before on password reset forms.  An email will contain a link, and the user's identity is confirmed only using the token.

Is doing this in my Twilio app secure?  Are there any gotchas to note?

Comment: How are you generating the token?

Comment: Currently I am using the PHP MD5 function on the concatenation of the user's database ID number, email, and padded an arbitrary string that doesn't change.

Comment: added a second half to my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as secure as any other request to your server from a remote HTTP client (like a browser). If you want to make sure that no one between Twilio's servers and yours can read the request, you should use HTTPS/SSL.

For this use case, it's probably better to associate the CallSid value that's sent with every request to your server with the user in your system. When the StatusCallback for a completed call fires, look up the user associated with that call and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A few of the browser-based single sign on protocols like OpenID and SAML use a similar technique to track state when redirecting between the site you're trying to authenticate to and the site doing the authentication.  I think the technique is good enough for what you want to achieve.

I'm not familiar with Twilio, but I'd be careful about using to identify a *user* though.  Generating a unique code (aka nonce) for every request and having Twilio pass that nonce back in the response would be more secure, as it only identifies a particular *request.*  It might be overkill though.